# ¿Cómo agregar elementos de pantalla de un dll?

Tags: c#

Buenos días comunidad,

estoy tratando de utilizar unos visores de documentos llamado gdPicture, lo instalé, añadí la referencia a mi proyecto del dll, pero no sé como puedo ver los elementos que este trae en mi toolbox. Trabajo con windows forms. La pregunta es, qué tengo que hacer para poder utilizar estos elementos. Es la primera vez que utilizo objetos que no vienen integrados.

Saludos!

Comment: Que tal, Intenta dar clic derecho en la tolbox y agregar elementos, ahí seleccionas la dll - > Aceptar y te deben aparecer los elementos una vez seleccionada

Comment: Ya me aparecen en la toolbox, pero... me tira la siguiete excepción:

Failed to create component 'AxHost'. The error message follows:
'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x8004d747):

The ActiveX type library '..../GdPicture.NET.14.tlb' was exported from a .NET assembly and cannot be added as a reference.